# Where to download param partition image for Meizu Pro5?

Tags: boot, partitioning, ubuntu-touch

I have a damaged "param" partition on my Meizu Pro 5 ubuntu edition.
I am now in recovery mode. a TWRP 3.0 adb enabled.

My param partition (a small 4M) (/dev/sda21) got wiped.

Can someone tell me:

What is that partition for?

Can I reboot without bricking the phone?

Where can I get a pristine image for this partition?

If someone else has a meizu pro5, can you provide it?

This partition image is not in the device-*.tar.gz from ubuntu system images.

Answer (score 0):

The partition is mostly empty. I have scavenged this info from another meziu pro5 phone.

Hope it will help another poor soul that will mess up the internal flash.

To recreate the partition information run this:

```
(head -c 320 /dev/zero
echo -e -n "\xCCUactivateStats\x00\xC0\x01\xC5\x04"
head -c 43 /dev/zero
echo -e -n "\xE3"
head -c 4193920 /dev/zero) > test.img
```

The md5sum of the partition should be: e69ac803431a05cf0b59d23129221861

Comment: @e.timotie I noticed you are pretty good with Meizu pro 5 now, I have been trying for over 5 hours now to resize the partition /system, /cache on Meizu Pro 5 but no success:-(. I pushed "parted" using Adb on the phone, which is running twrp as recovery. Phone has no OS because I have wiped it out, on reboot it display Meizu Ubuntu Powered .. That's all. Could you please elaborate on how you resized the partition? Thanks!

Comment: Well, it has been so long ago.

Comment: Well, it has been so long ago.
You start from this point, TWRP in recovery and the phone in recovery, you have adb.
You format the system partition so you have a place to untar the ubuntu system image (or ubports for that matter).
You upload the ubuntu system image into the /system

Comment: Now you have to create a fully functional (from dev,proc,sys pov) chroot environment:

mount -o bind /dev /system/dev ;
mount -o bind /proc /system/proc ;
mount -o bind /sys /system/sys ;

you now can do: chroot /system bash ;
and you have a more or less functional console only ubuntu system. Now you can call parted/fdisk to do the partitions.

The important thing is to respect the partition labeling since android is using the labels to mount the partitions.
This is not a copy&paste howto, but more like a hint, a direction.
Happy hacking.